# How to filter dates in dataraptor using literal dates

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio, vlocity

How can I make this work? or how to filter the date by a range?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I ended up finding the environment variables in the Omnistudio documentation. Example: $Vlocity.N_DAYS_AGO:30
[Documentation link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_environment_variables_in_dataraptors_and_integration_procedures_47878.htm&type=5)